# Apache virtualhost 403

Tags: apache, http-status-code-403, httpserver

I'm stuck on this 403 problem. I set up virtual host for apache on ubuntu, and when I access the site, it returns 403.

**/etc/apache2/site-available/os.solesschong.com**

```
<VirtualHost *>
    DocumentRoot /root/mysoft/sns
    ServerName oa.solesschong.com
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/oa.solesschong.com-error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/oa.solesschong.com-access.log combined
<Directory /root/mysoft/sns>
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

`# a2enable oa.solesschong.com`

**file**

```
root/mysoft/sns/index.php
```

**DNS**

```
oa.solesschong.com A-record: [IP of my server]
```

**browser return**

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at oa.solesschong.com Port 80
```

Comment: rights for 'all users' in the /root directory are certainly not the same as the one found in '/var' and '/var/www'. Anyway using '/root' to store such things is a very bad idea.

Comment: I saw somebody said apache has to have permission to parent folders. Does it mean the direct parent folder or all parent folders? If I interpret you right, I think you mean the latter.

Comment: You need the 'x' right for all users on parent directories. But the thing you need more is to avoid `/root`, not the right place.

Answer (score 2):

Does the Apache process have permission access to read to /root/mysoft/sns/index.php?

Answer (score 1):

Check your version of apache. If it is 2.4 then you need change alow configuration from

```
Allow from all
```

to

```
Require all granted
```